How to decrypt a CSR in golang with passphrase
I have a private key I've generated with openssl req that has passphrase.  I'm trying to decrypt it so I can add it to a tls certificate, but can't seem to decrypt it.  it fails at DecryptPEMBlock which is deprecated, but I can't seem to find an alternative to decrypting this private key
    privateKeyPEM, err := os.ReadFile("passcode-protected-private.key")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error reading private key: %v", err)
    }

    privateKeyBlock, _ := pem.Decode(privateKeyPEM)
    if privateKeyBlock == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to decode private key PEM")
    }

    privateKey, err := x509.DecryptPEMBlock(privateKeyBlock, []byte("my-password"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error decrypting private key: %v", err)
    }

I get the error:
"Failed to decrypt private key: x509: no DEK-Info header in block"
which isn't generated by my openssl req.  For certain reasons, I cannot change the openssl req command that I am running.  Is there another way to decrypt my encrypted private key?
My encrypted private key is of this format and with flags -newkey rsa:2048 and -sha256
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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...
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----


Encrypted PKCS#8 keys does not seem to be supported by crypto/x509, see #8860. Either convert to an encrypted PKCS#1 key (for compatibility with DecryptPEMBlock(), though this is already flagged as deprecated), e.g. with openssl, or try to find another package that supports encrypted PKCS#8 keys.

With regard to the latter, pkcs8.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey() is an option. This function expects a DER encoded key, i.e. the PEM encoded encrypted key must first be parsed with pem.Decode() (as in the current code).
